# I am trying to subtract one column from all the other columns in the dataframe (I have 500000 columns btw)

Tags: python, pandas, subtraction

I tried this:

```
for col in cols1:
    reg_df[col]=df[col] = reg_df[col].sub(reg_df['Intercept'])
    print(col)
```

Because I have 500,000 columns it is taking forever. Something like 220 hours. Is there anyway to speed up the process?

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

use broadcasting

```
out = reg_df.sub(reg_df['Intercept'], axis=0)
```

---

**Sameple**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
reg_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, (10, 500000))).rename({0: 'Intercept'}, axis=1)
```

1. vectorized operation

```
import time

start = time.time()

out = reg_df.sub(reg_df['Intercept'], axis=0)

end = time.time()

print(f"{end - start:.5f} sec")
```

time:

```
0.01237 sec
```

2. your for loop

```
start = time.time()

cols1 = reg_df.columns
for col in cols1:
    reg_df[col] = reg_df[col].sub(reg_df['Intercept'])

end = time.time()

print(f"{end - start:.5f} sec")
```

time:

```
It has been 10 minutes and it is still not finished.
```

Use vectorized operations.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I have tried it. Its running. fingers crossed

Answer (score 0):

You can use a vectorized approach for this.

```py
import pandas as pd

reg_df.iloc[:, 1:] = reg_df.iloc[:, 1:].sub(reg_df['Intercept'], axis=0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . I have tried it. Its running. fingers crossed